# JavaScript, if submit is true (using colorbox and jquery validate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, colorbox

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin for a form contained in a colorbox. I want to close the colorbox and open a second colorbox (saying thank you) if the validation is successful, and then send the user to their original destination.

The script captures the destination of the user and puts it in a variable, then opens a colorbox. Users can exist the colorbox in four different ways, clicking off the bock, clicking the x in the upper right corner, clicking the close button, or a successful submit. Then they continue on their way.

What I need is something like an if submit successful, then open thank you colorbox. What I've tried so far just breaks everything.

```
$('#lookUpSubmit').unbind('click').click(function(){
    $form.submit();
});

$("#lookUpCancel").unbind('click').click(function(){
    $.colorbox.close();
});

$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    window.location = destination_url;
});

$form.validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    },
//some stuff
});
```

Comment: If you create a http://jsfiddle.net with your code, I'd be happy to look over it and help out.

Comment: Hey, that's kinda nifty.

http://jsfiddle.net/absynthe_minded_web_smith/Jk8sK/1/

Answer (score 0):

What exactly happens when de submit was successful ? Do you redirect to a page or something ? As far as JavaScript is Client based you have no influence or whatsoever on where the server brings you. You could implement the Thank You Popup on the Webpage which you are redirected after a successful submit !

Comment: What happens is that when the user clicks out of a certain section of the website, we popup a modal window, as a few questions then send them on their way. It will only catch people going to other parts of our site, since we don't have any external links in this part of the website.

Answer (score 0):

The information you've provided is a bit vague. What do you mean specifically by "everything breaks"?

What you describe could be caused by a number of things:
Is $form actually defined somewhere, or did you mean to use $(form)?
Have you verified that your unbind/bind chaining is working properly?

```
    $('#lookUpSubmit').unbind('click').click(function(){
        alert("B2K Was Here!"); 
    });
```

Submitting a form will reload the page or redirect to the action url. You need to prevent the submission.

```
$('#formid').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // validate here
  if ( valid ) {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: this.action,
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function() {
           // open thank you colorbox here
       }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry. $form is defined as var $form = $(this).parents('form').first(),

That woks fine.

When I do an alert, it also works fine.

So what happens when I don't try to launch a second colorbox is that the form submits normally and the colorbox closes. We've been using this and it works.

What happens when I add     $.colorbox({href:"some_url.html",title:" "}); depends on where I put it. If I put it in the lookupsubmit function, is that the initial colorbox won't launch at all.

If I put it in the submit handler, it opens the second colorbox as a page.